# Don't have the permissions to open several items in Sharepoint Designer!

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have download the trial-version of Sharepoint 365 and then i have downloaded the Sharepoint Designer 2013. Then I have connect Sharepoint Designer to my Sharepoint teamsite. But then when i want to use Sharepoint Designer most of the items are permission denied. How can I set the right-permission? I don't understand i have setup these environments, Sharepoint contains only one user: ME. But I don't have the permission on several items in the Sharepoint Designer. How can i solve this? Gr. P

Comment: what is your user role in your Tenant? Are you a Site Collection Admin?

Comment: How can i see my permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

1. Please check your user role via Microsoft 365 admin center. You will need an extra user in your tenant since you cannot edit your own settings.

   Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role
2. Make sure you are a site collection administrator of the team site via *Settings (Gear button on top right of the page) > Site permissions > Advanced permissions settings > Site Collection Administrators*.

   But since you are the only user in your tenant, you should be the site collection administrator by default.
3. Make sure you have enabled custom script on both tenant level and site level. Please note that any change in the SharePoint admin center may take up to 24 hours to take effect.

   Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script#to-allow-custom-script-on-other-sharepoint-sites